# How to Increase PC Volume With Python?

Tags: windows, audio, volume

I Just Want to increase sound volume like 110% 150% .. i find a code that not working. can anyone Suggest the actual code

```
import platform
import os

def increase_volume(percent):
    if platform.system() == "Linux":
        os.system("pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 +" + str(percent) + "%")
    elif platform.system() == "Windows":
        os.system("wmic sound set /volume:" + str(percent))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    percent = 10  # The percentage by which to increase the volume
    increase_volume(percent)
```

Write a efficient code to increase the sound volume